# When to use the atomic clause and single worksharing construct in openMP programs?

Tags: openmp

I'm just beginning to learn to use OpenMP. I'm curious about when one would use the **single** work sharing construct and when one would use the **atomic** clause.

From what I've read so far, the **atomic clause seems redundant**. The **single** construct denotes a block of code that is executed by only one thread (not necessarily the master thread) and the **atomic** clause provides mutual exclusion but only applies to the update of a memory location (the update of X in the following example).

Despite the extra condition placed on the **atomic** clause (that it can only be used in update situations), it seems like the **single** construct is capable of achieving everything the **atomic** clause can.

I know I'm missing something, can someone please motivate the existence of the **atomic** clause ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two directives are completely different.

`single` does not provide any mechanism related to mutual exclusion or instruction atomic. As a result, a `single` section can work on a shared variable modified by other threads. Your are confused because you probably assumes that others threads are not doing anything during a `single` section. This is wrong. Indeed, threads could finish a `parallel for` (or another `single` section) with a `nowait` close or could also create OpenMP tasks executed during the `single` section, etc.
Here is an example:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel
{
    ...

    // This section does not wait for others threads
    #pragma omp master
    {
        // some computation
        int a = rand();
        // some computation
    }

    // This section wait for others threads only at the end
    #pragma omp single
    {
        // some computation
        int b = rand();
        // some computation
    }

    ...
}
```

In the code above, the two `rand` calls can be executed in parallel (because the `master` section can be executed by one thread while another thread run the `single` section).
Since `rand` is not thread safe, this can cause undefined results (probably a race condition). Moreover, please note that using a `single` directive does not make the `rand` call atomic.

In order to avoid race conditions, you can use synchronization directives such as `barrier` or `taskwait`. You can also use mutual exclusion using `critical` or atomic instructions using `atomic`.
Synchronizations directives should be avoided (when it is possible) as they often cause scalability issues. `atomic` instructions can only be applied on specific cases. For example, you cannot use `atomic` directives on the `rand` calls in the code above. However, you can use `critical` sections to *protect* these calls (while keeping the `single` and `master` sections that can be executed in parallel).

`atomic` should be preferred over `critical` when both make sense because the overhead of `atomic` instructions is generally smaller.
An `atomic` directive cannot be replaced by only a `single` directive because the `atomic` is performed by each thread of the parallel section while the `single` section is executed by only one.